# mv, rename if exists

Tags: linux, mv

I need to assemble a lot of images into one directory. Many of those images have the same file names.

Is there some safe version of `mv` that will automatically rename files if the target filename already exists so that `pic1.jpeg` becomes something like `pic1_2.jpeg`?

I could write my own python script but there has to be something like this out there so I can do:

```
find . -type f -name *.jpg -exec mvsafe '{}' /targetpath/ \;
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

mv already supports this out of the box (at least in Debian):

```
mv --backup=t <source_file> <dest_file>
```

As seen in mv(1) manpage:

```
--backup[=CONTROL]
         make a backup of each existing destination file

The  backup  suffix  is  `~',  unless  set  with   --suffix   or   SIM‐
PLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.   The version control method may be selected via the
--backup option or through the  VERSION_CONTROL  environment  variable.
```

To make `--backup=t` mean "make numbered backups", invoke as follows:

```
env VERSION_CONTROL=numbered mv --backup=t <source_file> <dest_file>
```

(dest_file can of course be a directory).

Edit: in later versions (at least GNU coreutils 8.22 but prolly already much earlier) you can simply write

```
mv --backup=numbered <source_file> <dest_file>
```

Comment: +1 for an amazingly clean solution. BTW the option is present on RHEL 6 too.

Comment: While nice functionality, this does not really help that much in my case since it will append the suffix after the extension, so the files will end up with names like .jpg~1~ while I would need them to be named _1.jpg. I will probably use mmv to rename the files after moving them.

Comment: this is the mmv command that will achieve my desired result after doing mv --backup=numbered:   mmv -v "*.*.~*~" "#1_#3.#2"

Comment: On my Debian system (mmv 1.01b-18), the correct mmv command is: `mmv -v "*.*~*~" "#1_#3.#2"`

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 20.10 as `mv --backup=numbered <source> <dest>` but isn't documented in the man page.

Comment: Hey, it only took me 9 years to accept this answer... A belated thanks.

Comment: For anyone interested I posted a solution (`sed` regex) to rename e.g. `banana.txt.~1~` to `banana_1.txt` (all such files in a directory). https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624990/135372

Answer (score 0):

`move` command rename file if file exists.

### Install

```
node install -g @gauravnumber/move
```

### Example

```
move *.jpg dirname
```

[link to repo](https://github.com/gauravnumber/move.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not what is expected from all "move" program (and in Windows it does behave like in Linux). This is unexpected, it should be an option, not the default behavior.